# How do I modify this e.preventDefault to work on all pages except the homepage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, colorbox

I'm having trouble with a bit of script in getting ColorBox to work on my site.

Originally it was coded to override the default link follow 'launch(this);' whenever the class .boxElement was found on a link.

I've tried to modify it so that the override only happens when it is not the homepage, but it doesn't seem to trigger. Instead it just prevents the override on all pages.

```
$('.' + boxElement, document).live('click', function (e) {
   if ( !is_home() ) {
       e.preventDefault();
       launch(this);
   } else { return true; }
});
```

Could anyone provide some assistance? I'm sure it is a simple mistake.

Comment: Can you show us your `is_home()` function please?

Comment: The `.live()` function has been deprecated for months now (since jQuery 1.7 was released), and was removed entirely in 1.9. You should switch to using either `.on()` (1.7+) or `.delegate()` - view the docs for `.live()` for details on converting from one to the other.

Comment: @BenM - I have a funny feeling this is a PHP and JS mashup.  is_home() is a built in Wordpress PHP function.  Am I right Taylor?

Comment: Indeed, that's what I was thinking too!

Comment: @McNab - Indeed indeed, that was the error. I am new, lost, and confused :/ Alen's answer below put me onto the right track. Thank you guys so much, it truly is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This function should return true for your home page

```
   var is_home = function(){
      return window.location.href.indexOf("some_part_of_home_url") > -1;
   }
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you. As @McNab pointed out I was mixing up my code a little bit. Thanks a bunch, it is truly appreciated!